# Android show plurals in both integer and float

Tags: android

My target is to show text like "1 star" "2.5 stars" "3 stars".

which is remove `.0` for float value like `1.0, 2.0 etc.` But for the value with `.5` show the float value `2.5 3.5 etc.`

Is this possible to use android `plurals` ?

I used this way but doesn't work.
**plurals.xml**

```
<plurals name="hotel_card_rating_text">
        <item quantity="zero">@string/text_zero</item>
        <item quantity="one">@string/text_one</item>
        <item quantity="two">@string/text_two</item>
        <item quantity="few">@string/text_few</item>
        <item quantity="many">@string/text_many</item>
        <item quantity="other">@string/text_other</item>
    </plurals>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="text_zero">%.1f stars</string>
    <string name="text_one">1 star</string>
    <string name="text_two">%.1f stars</string>
    <string name="text_few">%.1f stars</string>
    <string name="text_many">%.1f stars</string>
    <string name="text_other">%.1f stars</string>
</resources>
```

**test code**

```
 DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();                    
    float rating = getRating();
    getStarText().setText(getContext().getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.hotel_card_rating_text, (int) rating, format.format(rating)));
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**strings.xml** use `%s` instead of `%.1f`

```
<resources>
    <string name="text_zero">%s stars</string>
    <string name="text_one">1 star</string>
    <string name="text_two">%s stars</string>
    <string name="text_few">%s stars</string>
    <string name="text_many">%s stars</string>
    <string name="text_other">%s stars</string>
</resources>
```

test code

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#"); // format the number
float rating = getRating();
getContext().getResources()
    .getQuantityString(R.plurals.hotel_card_rating_text, (int) rating, format.format(rating)));
```

Be careful when you use plurals. It has its own issues, see below:

[Plural definition is ignored for zero quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261290/plural-definition-is-ignored-for-zero-quantity)

[Issue 8287: PluralRules does not handle quantity "zero"](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8287)

Comment: The `zero`quantity doesn't have issues - it's just a common misunderstanding of how the quantities work and what the purpose of them is. For example, `zero`, `one` and `two` does not map directly to the exact numbers 0, 1 and 2 respectively, and as such they are not used by all languages (even though the numbers obviously can be used by all languages).

Answer (score 1):

you can give it a try to below snippet which is very typical

```
String somePostFixText = "star";
String output;
double starCount;

if (starCount > (double)1)
      somePostFixText = somePostFixText+"s";

if(starCount == (long) starCount){
       output = String.format("%d",(long)starCount)+" "+somePostFixText;
} else {
       output = String.format("%s",starCount)+" "+somePostFixText;
}

//do whatever you want to do with output variable
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: ahh..! okay i guess above code will work with your mechanism too just a little changes by converting values into static resources you can achieve what you want.