# How to use Android quantity strings (plurals)

Tags: android, string, android-resources, plural

I am trying to use the [getQuantityString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getQuantityString(int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object...)) method in Resources to retrieve *quantity strings* (plurals) based on Android Developer guidelines [Quantity string (plurals)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals)

The error I am getting is

> Error:(604) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute? 
> Error:(604) Found tag  where  is expected

when I set up plurals as below

```
<plurals name="productCount">
    <item quantity="one" formatted="true">%1$d of %2$d product</item>
    <item quantity="other" formatted="true">%1$d of %2$d products</item>
</plurals>
```

And trying to read it as below

```java
productIndexCountText.setText(getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.productCount, position, size));
```

One workaround is to break the string up to use plural only for the last part of the string and concatenate the two parts. But I am trying to avoid doing that if possible.

Comment: for others who looking for similar information, here is the official guide. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You don't need to set the "formatted" attribute for any of those items. When using quantity strings, there are only three possibilities:

1. the resource string is plain text and does not contain any parameters
2. the resource string contains only one parameter (most likely the quantity); use `%d` or whatever format you need
3. the resource string contains multiple parameters; all parameters have to be explicitly accessed by their position, for example `%1$d`

As for the `getQuantityString` method, there are two overloads: one with only the resource id and the quantity, and one with an additional `Object... formatArgs` parameter.

For case 1., you can use the `getQuantityString(@PluralsRes int id, int quantity)` method.

For all other cases, i. e. if you have *any* parameters, you need the `getQuantityString(@PluralsRes int id, int quantity, Object... formatArgs)` overload. Note: **all** parameters have to be present in the parameter array. That means, if the resource string displays the quantity, the quantity variable will be passed **twice** to the function.

That is because the `quantity` parameter of the method itself is not considered when resolving the positional parameters of your resource string.

So if these are your resources,

```
<resources>
    <plurals name="test0">
        <item quantity="one">Test ok</item>
        <item quantity="other">Tests ok</item>
    </plurals>
    <plurals name="test1">
        <item quantity="one">%d test ok</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d tests ok</item>
    </plurals>
    <plurals name="test2">
        <item quantity="one">%2$s: %1$d test ok</item>
        <item quantity="other">%2$s: %1$d tests ok</item>
    </plurals>
    <plurals name="test3">
        <item quantity="one">%3$s: %1$d test out of %2$d ok</item>
        <item quantity="other">%3$s: %1$d tests out of %2$d ok</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

then the appropriate calls to `getQuantityString` are:

```java
int success = 1;
int total = 10;
String group = "Group name";

getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test0, success)
// Test ok
getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test1, success, success)
// 1 test ok
getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test2, success, success, group)
// Group name: 1 test ok
getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test3, success, success, total, group)
// Group name: 1 test out of 10 ok

success = 5;
getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test0, success)
// Tests ok
getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test1, success, success)
// 5 tests ok
getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test2, success, success, group)
// Group name: 5 tests ok
getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test3, success, success, total, group)
// Group name: 5 tests out of 10 ok
```

---

#### Quantity classes: understanding the `quantity` parameter

As stated above, the key is to understand that the `quantity` parameter of `getQuantityString` is not used to replace the placeholders like `%d` or `%1$d`. Instead, it is used to determine the appropriate `item` from the `plurals` itself, in combination with the locale of the resource file.

Beware however that this is a less direct mapping than the attribute's name and its possible values (`zero`, `one`, `two`, `few`, `many`, `other`) might suggest. For example, providing an additional `<item quantity="zero">` [will not work (at least not in English)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17261290/1843468), even if the value of the `quantity` parameter is 0.

The reason is that the way `plurals` work in Android is by the concept of **quantity classes**. A quantity class is a set of quantity values that have the same grammatical rules in a given language. This crucially means that

- which quantity classes are used, and
- which numeric values are mapped to them

is dependent on the locale the respective resource file is for.

It is important to understand that both questions are decided only by *grammatical necessity*. Here are some examples:

- In Chinese or Korean, only `other` is used, because in these languages sentences don't grammatically differ based on the given quantity.
- In English, there's two classes: `one` for the literal value 1, and `other` for all other values including 0.
- In Irish, 1 is mapped to `one`, 2 is mapped to `two`, 3-6 is `few`, 7-10 is `many`, 0 and 11+ is `other`.
- In Slovenian, the value 1 **and** all values *ending* in 01 are mapped to `one` (1, 101, 3001, ...). 2 and values ending in 02 are mapped to `two` (2, 302, 1002, ...). 3, 4 and values ending in 03 or 04 are mapped to `few` (3, 4, 6004, ...). Anything else is `other` (0, 11, 48, 312, ...).
- In Polish, 5-19 and values ending in 05-19 are mapped to `many` (5, 12, 216, 4711, ...). Values ending in 2, 3 or 4 including 2-4 themselves are mapped to `few` (3, 42, 103, 12035374, ...). This respects however that 12, 13 and 14 are exceptions from this rule because they are mapped to `many`. (Side note: yes, grammatically speaking, 5 is *many* while 12035374 is *few*.)
- Armenian is like English, with the exception that the value 0 is also mapped to `one`, because that's how their grammar works. You can see from this example that the quantity class `one` doesn't even necessarily represent just one-ish numbers.

As you can see, it can get fairly complicated to determine the correct quantity class. That's why `getQuantityString` already does that for you, based on the `quantity` parameter and the resource file's locale. The rules Android (mostly) plays by are defined in the [Language Plural Rules](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) of the [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](https://cldr.unicode.org/index/charts). That is also where the names of the quantity classes come from.

All that means that the set of quantity classes needed to translate any quantity string can differ from language to language (Chinese just needs `other`, English needs `one` and `other`, Irish needs all but `zero`, etc.). Within one language however, all `plurals` should each have the same number of items covering all quantity classes necessary for that particular language.

##### Conclusion

A call to `getQuantityString` can be understood like this:

```java
int success = 5;
int total = 10;
String group = "Group name";

getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test3, success, success, total, group)
//                               \_____________/  \_____/  \___________________/
//                                      |            |               |
//         id: used to get the plurals resource      |               |
//   quantity: used to determine the appropriate quantity class      |
// formatArgs: used to positionally replace the placeholders %1, %2 and %3
```

The `quantity` parameter's value of "5" will mean the used `item` will be the one with the quantity class `other` from Chinese, Korean, English, Slovenian and Armenian resource files, `few` for Irish, and `many` for Polish.

---

There are two special cases I'd also briefly mention:

#### Non-integer quantities

Basically, the chosen class depends on language-specific rules again. It is neither universal how a class is chosen, nor guaranteed that any class required to cover all rules for integers is also used for any non-integers. Here are a few examples:

- For English, any value with decimals will always map to `other`.
- For Slovenian, any value with decimals will always map to `few`.
- For Irish, the choice depends on the integer part.
- For Polish, in contrast to the complex rules for integers, non-integers are always mapped to `other` like in English.

**Note:** This is how it *should* be according to the [Language Plural Rules](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html). Alas, Android has no readily available method for `float` or `double` at the moment.

#### Multiple quantities in one string

If your display text has multiple quantities, e. g. `%d match(es) found in %d file(s).`, split it into **three** separate resources:

1. `%d match(es)` (`plurals` item)
2. `%d file(s)` (`plurals` item)
3. `%1$s found in %2$s.` (ordinary parameterized `strings` item)

You can then make the appropriate calls to `getQuantityString` for 1 and 2, and then another one to `getString` for the third, with the first two readily localized strings as `formatArgs`.

The reason is to allow translators to switch the parameter order in the third resource, should the language require it. E.g., if the only valid syntax in a hypothetical language was `In %d file(s) it found %d match(es).`, the translator could translate the plurals as usual, and then translate the third resource as `In %2$s it found %1$s.` to account for the swapped order.

Comment: What about if there are two or more words that need plural change, like
"Found %1$d result(s) in %2$d chapter(s)". I want both result(s) and chapter(s) to be able to modify themselves. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What if the quantity is Float like distance? i want to show 1 km or 1.5 kms

Comment: @BugsHappen You'd have to split the translation into multiple parts then. Best practise is to split it in not two but three parts then: `%d result(s)`, `%d chapter(s)`, and `Found %1$s in %2$s`. This allows a hypothetical language to change the word order in the sentence where necessary (e. g. if a language's syntax was `In %d chapter(s), %d result(s) were found.`), which would be impossible if you just split the sentence in two parts and concatenated them in the code.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I did. I asked because I thought maybe there is a better way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sniper I'm actually still pondering about this from time to time. TBH the most difficult thing for me is to decide how I'd _want_ the plural to behave. In German (my mother tongue), the plural of "km" is still "km", so that doesn't help. And in English, I don't know, wouldn't you say "one point five miles" but "one and a half mile" for "1.5 mi"? Or in other words, do units as such do have a plural anyway?