# How to a xml string to an string output

Tags: java, android

Using Android Studio and I would like to know how to get "months" to pick up a string from xml string please. (Just learning android at the moment). Need to pick up from strings.xml as I need to translate that to another language.

```
else if (human_year == 0) {
        return Integer.toString(Math.round(human_month)) + " months";
```

output: years - which can be translated into Spanish (this is working have set up a button to translate) currently all words linked back to a string.xml are being translated. As this "months" is not attached to a string it is not being translated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Android quantity strings (plurals)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950952/how-to-use-android-quantity-strings-plurals)

Comment: ^ it's not an exact duplicate, but it explains the combination of plurals and string format.

Answer (score 1):

First declare "months" in

> English strings (default locale), /values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="myStringMonths">months</string>
</resources>
```

then for spanish

> Spanish strings (es locale), /values-es/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="myStringMonths">meses</string>
</resources>
```

then in your code take it as below:

```
else if (human_year == 0) {
        return  String.format("%d", Math.round(human_month)) + getString(R.id.myStringMonths);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ["Quantity String"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getQuantityString(int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object...)) for this.

Create a `plurals.xml` files in your Resources directory. Then populate it with something along the lines of:

```
<resources>
    <plurals name="months">
        <item quantity="one">%1$d month</item>
        <item quantity="other">%1$d months</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

You can create a different file for different locales.

You can then access it in your code with:

```
final int months = Math.round(human_month);
return resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.months, months, months)
```

Comment: using quantity strings is indeed better, while the `final` keyword is useless.

Comment: @MartinZeitler More a question of coding style - I mark everything `final` unless it needs to be mutated

Comment: @MartinZeitler I still like it because it signifies intention - but you can leave it out, I'm not precious about it

Comment: in this case, it's a `final` local variable... where it's kind of verbosity overkill. there are situations, where the compiler produces less code, due to optimization - but on the other hand, the `GC` handles these differently. the values can still be mutated, it's only the reference to them that is `final`.