# How to stringify quantities/numbers in different locales grammatically correct in android java

Tags: java, android, string, locale, number-formatting

I'm working on a native android app (java) which supports different locales: `en, fr, de, es, pt, it, ru, ar`

I need to display a number of objects to the user

> example: You have 7 days left

what I used to do is provide a double-from translation for the same sentence, One for the singluar form and the other for the plural

```java
private static final String SENTENCE_SINGLE = "You have 1 day left"; 
private static final String SENTENCE_PLURAL = "You have %d days left"; 

public String stringify(number) {
  if (number < 0)
    return null;
  if (number == 1)
    return SENTENCE_SINGLE;
  return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, SENTENCE_PLURAL, number);
}
```

This works fine with `English` and `French`. But when I'm dealing with `Arabic` for example, I have to consider a sentence for the number 2, and another for every first 10 numbers in each 100th. (Kinda complicated, I know)

for refrence

```java
// The arabic way
private static final String SENTENCE_SINGLE = "You have 1 day left"; 
private static final String SENTENCE_DOUBLE = "You have two-days left"; 
private static final String SENTENCE_PLURAL = "You have %d days left";  
private static final String SENTENCE_PLURAL_FIRST_10 = "You have %d special-way-day left"; 

public String stringify(number) {
  if (number < 0)
    return null;
  if (number == 1)
    return SENTENCE_SINGLE;
  if (number == 2)
    return SENTENCE_DOUBLE;
  if (number % 100 <= 10 && number % 100 >= 2)
    return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, SENTENCE_PLURAL_FIRST_10, number);
  return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, SENTENCE_PLURAL, number);
}
```

I should have a unified function for all locales. I still can work with this method, even though I will be using redundant sentences for simple locales like

```java
// for English
private static final String SENTENCE_SINGLE = "You have 1 day left"; 
private static final String SENTENCE_DOUBLE = "You have 2 days left"; 
private static final String SENTENCE_PLURAL = "You have %d days left";  
private static final String SENTENCE_PLURAL_FIRST_10 = "You have %d days left";
```

The problem is I have no Idea how the grammar in the other languages work ***(de|German, es|Spanish, pt|Portugese, it|Italian, ru|Russian)***, I'm mostly working with google translate :)

Is there an existing library I can use, or can someone explain how numbers work in the other languages,

Comment: So yet another generation of developers re-invents [`MessageFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/MessageFormat). That won't help you solve the question of "how do I phrase this in russian", you'll still need translators for that, but it provides the technical base.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Android quantity strings (plurals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950952/how-to-use-android-quantity-strings-plurals). Android has a tool for this already - called a "quantity string". You'd made a version for each locale in that local's resource XML file that uses the appropriate grammar.

Comment: Unfortunately , this fails to deal with arabic because I can't define a way for the `number % 100` condition, and that's base of my question: How to deal with all (weird) locales